# Making source/header files in a library read-only?

Tags: c++

As an example: In visual studio right-click on any function that is in the standard library and click "Go To Definition", it will show the definition in a header or source file that is read-only.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't see what's the point of that. Even if the header file were read-only file, you could easily copy & paste it and modify it if you want to. What are you trying to solve or hide here?

Comment: @Pablo: I'm trying to prevent accidental modification. Not intentional modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the files as read-only when you distribute them. This offers the minimum amount the protection, as the permissions can be restored easily. Even from Visual Studio, if you attempt to overwrite the file, it will bring up a dialog that asks for confirmation of removal of read-only protection. This also happens for standard library headers.

Comment: That's what I usually do, just mark the includes as readonly, but I always fear a potential update. Should Microsoft decide to update a header this could be disastrous. Did you encounter any such issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Just mark the source or header file as read-only in the Windows Explorer!! :)

Comment: What about the files contained in a .lib?

Comment: Can you browse to a .lib? All the trick of visual studio that show its system headers and source files as read-only is following read-only mark of the file. You can also set this for .lib files but be sure for a programmer like me that love to work with code of libraries even visual studio can't stop me from changing std headers!! so this is just minimum protection